# Jmeter - How to loop x times based on items in the array (JSON extractor + ForEach controller)

Tags: jmeter

I have JSON array consist of dynamic number of items as.

```
{
"pageItems": [
    {
        "description": "test1",
        "transDescription": "",
        "eventType": "",
        "eventCode": "",
        "bonusType": "PROGRAM",
        "validFrom": null,
        "validTo": null,
        "maxUsage": 0,
        "tncLabel": "",
        "enabled": true,
        "staffName": "",
        "bonusReason": "TEST",
        "programId": 3,
        "isTemplate": false,
        "sourceProgramId": 0,
        "currentUsage": 1,
        "playerListName": "",
        "playerCount": 0
        
    },
    {
        "description": "test2",
        "transDescription": "",
        "eventType": "",
        "eventCode": "",
        "bonusType": "PROGRAM",
        "validFrom": null,
        "validTo": null,
        "maxUsage": 0,
        "tncLabel": "",
        "enabled": true,
        "staffName": "",
        "bonusReason": "",
        "programId": 2,
        "isTemplate": false,
        "sourceProgramId": 0,
        "currentUsage": 0,
        "playerListName": "",
        "playerCount": 0         
    },
    {
        "description": "test3",
        "transDescription": "",
        "eventType": "",
        "eventCode": "",
        "bonusType": "",
        "validFrom": null,
        "validTo": null,
        "maxUsage": 0,
        "tncLabel": "",
        "enabled": true,
        "staffName": "",
        "bonusReason": "",
        "programId": 1,
        "isTemplate": false,
        "sourceProgramId": 0,
        "currentUsage": 0,
        "playerListName": "",
        "playerCount": 0
    }
],
"totalItemCount": 3
```

}

I want to change "enabled" to false, for every single child element of the JSON- pageItems.
This JSON array is dynamic and every single time consists of a different amount of items

I believe I can use ForEach Controller, and JSON extractor, but I dont know how to build my logic here.

***edit***:

My whole logic is like this:

[image]

The update should be done by endpoint as:

[image]

Now the question is: How to tell ForEach controller to loop x times based on the items in the JSON?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "change"?

If you want to:

1. Get the response
2. Change `enabled` to `false`
3. Store the resulting JSON into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

you can do it using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

response.pageItems.each { pageItem -> pageItem.enabled = false }

vars.put('response', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString())
```

If you additionally want to save each "pageItem" into a separate JMeter Variable suitable for iterating via ForEach Controller you can add another piece of code:

```
response.pageItems.eachWithIndex { pageItem, index ->
    vars.put('item_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(pageItem).toPrettyString())
}
```

As the result you will have the following variables:

- `${response}` - containing the original response with the modified `enabled` attribute
- `${item_1}`, `${item_2}`, etc. variables containing individual "items"

More information: [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)

Comment: Hey @Dmitri T, I just update my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to fetch all `programId` values using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor), the following [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query: `$..programId` and setting Match Nr to `-1` and then use this variable in the ForEach Controller and in the Path field of the HTTP Request sampler, i.e. put `programId` in the JSON Extractor and ForEach Controller input and output variable and `${programId}` to the HTTP Request sampler's Path